# Numerical issue in MATLAB maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: matlab, optimization, statistics

I am using `mle` and `mlecov` to estimate the mean and variance of the scalar noise signal `n` which is assumed to be normally distributed with the following models for mean and standard deviation:

```
mean(x,y) = @(x,y) k(1)+k(2)*x+k(3)*x.^2+k(4)*y+k(5)*y.^2;
sd(x,y)  = @(x,y) k(6)+k(7)*x+k(8)*x.^2+k(9)*y+k(10)*y.^2;
```

where `x` is in the [0,3] interval and and `y` is in the [0,pi/2] interval (thus, scaling does not immediately seem to be an issue). The sample of `n`, `x` and `y` values used for MLE has 10981 samples. Here are some graphs to show the sample qualitatively:

[image]
Figure 1. Histogram of the noise samples.

[image]
Figure 2. Scatter plot of the noise samples vs. the x and y samples respectively.

My goal is to compute the maximum likelihood estimates for the `k(i)` model parameters, `i=1,...,10`, as well as their standard deviation, `kSE(i)` (given by the square root of the diagonal elements of the asymptotic covariance matrix output by `mlecov`).

For the maximum likelihood estimation, I minimize the negative log likelihood:

[image]

I also give MATLAB the analytical gradient of the negative log likelihood `L(k(1),...,k(10))`, used by `mle` and `mlecov` such that numerical approximations of the gradient hopefully do not contribute to the numerical issue I am about to describe.

**Numerical Issue**

To demonstrate the issue, I present three scenarios.

*Scenario 1*. I directly run `mle` and `mlecov` on the sample data. This outputs the following Stata-like summary:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Coeffs   |      Val.     Std. Err.       z      P>|z|    [95% Conf. Interval]
---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
   k1    |   -0.0153      0.0014     -11.27     0.000     -0.0179    -0.0126 
   k2    |    0.0075      0.0016       4.79     0.000      0.0045     0.0106 
   k3    |    0.0045      0.0006       7.44     0.000      0.0033     0.0056 
   k4    |    0.0131      0.0023       5.57     0.000      0.0085     0.0177 
   k5    |   -0.0101      0.0012      -8.45     0.000     -0.0125    -0.0078 
   k6    |    0.0114      0.0011      10.25     0.000      0.0092     0.0135 
   k7    |    0.0244      0.0011      21.86     0.000      0.0222     0.0266 
   k8    |   -0.0001      0.0004      -0.34     0.732     -0.0010     0.0007 
   k9    |   -0.0190      0.0018     -10.48     0.000     -0.0225    -0.0154 
   k10   |    0.0057      0.0009       6.32     0.000      0.0039     0.0074 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The "Val." column corresponds to the `k(i)` estimates and the "Std. Err." column corresponds to `kSE(i)`. The "P>|z|" column gives the p-value for a single coefficient Wald test of the null hypothesis `k(i)==0` (if this p-value is `<0.05`, we reject the null hypothesis and thus conclude that the coefficient `k(i)` may be significant at the 95% level).

Note that to compute the asymptotic covariance matrix of the `k(i)` estimates, `mlecov` computes the Hessian `H` of `L(k(1),...,k(10))` - which I provide an analytic gradient for. The condition number of `H` is `cond(H)=2.7437e3`. The `mlecov` function does a Cholesky factorization of the Hessian, which gives the upper-triangular matrix `R` with `cond(R)=52.38`.

*Scenario 2*. I multiply all samples by `0.1` and thus run `mle` and `mlecov` on the sample data `n*0.1`, `x*0.1` and `y*0.1`. This outputs the following summary:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Coeffs   |      Val.     Std. Err.       z      P>|z|    [95% Conf. Interval]
---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
   k1    |   -0.0010      0.0001      -7.39     0.000     -0.0013    -0.0008 
   k2    |    0.0063      0.0016       3.97     0.000      0.0032     0.0093 
   k3    |    0.0494      0.0060       8.21     0.000      0.0376     0.0611 
   k4    |    0.0023      0.0024       0.95     0.340     -0.0024     0.0070 
   k5    |   -0.0462      0.0123      -3.75     0.000     -0.0704    -0.0221 
   k6    |    0.0014      0.0001      12.30     0.000      0.0012     0.0016 
   k7    |    0.0220      0.0011      20.86     0.000      0.0200     0.0241 
   k8    |    0.0078      0.0042       1.87     0.062     -0.0004     0.0160 
   k9    |   -0.0228      0.0020     -11.27     0.000     -0.0267    -0.0188 
   k10   |    0.0747      0.0097       7.70     0.000      0.0557     0.0937 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**The p-values have changed**. Also, now `cond(H)=9.3831e5` (!!!) and `cond(R)=968.6616`. Note that when I remove the second order terms (`x.^2` and `y.^2`) from the mean and standard deviation models, there is no longer this problem (i.e. the p-values stay the same and the `k(i)` values, except for the constant terms `k(1)` and `k(6)`, are simply scaled by 0.1). Does this indicate a numerical issue?

*Scenario 3*. I decided to also try scaling `n`, `x` and `y` to the interval [-1,1] by dividing their samples by the largest element (i.e. `n(i)=n(i)/max(abs(n))`, `x(i)=x(i)/max(abs(x))` and `y(i)=y(i)/max(abs(y))`). Running `mle` and `mlecov` on this scaled sample outputs the following summary:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Coeffs   |      Val.     Std. Err.       z      P>|z|    [95% Conf. Interval]
---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
   k1    |   -0.0347      0.0041      -8.40     0.000     -0.0428    -0.0266 
   k2    |    0.1193      0.0141       8.46     0.000      0.0917     0.1470 
   k3    |    0.0482      0.0164       2.94     0.003      0.0160     0.0803 
   k4    |   -0.0002      0.0120      -0.02     0.987     -0.0238     0.0234 
   k5    |   -0.0305      0.0103      -2.96     0.003     -0.0506    -0.0103 
   k6    |    0.0557      0.0035      16.11     0.000      0.0489     0.0624 
   k7    |    0.1131      0.0107      10.60     0.000      0.0922     0.1341 
   k8    |    0.1164      0.0128       9.13     0.000      0.0914     0.1414 
   k9    |   -0.1132      0.0094     -11.99     0.000     -0.1317    -0.0947 
   k10   |    0.0583      0.0079       7.37     0.000      0.0428     0.0738 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**The p-values have changed again**! Now `cond(H)=4.7550e3` (higher than Scenario 1 (unscaled) but lower than Scenario 2 (everything multiplied by 0.1)). Also, `cond(R)=68.9565`, which is only slightly higher than for Scenario 1.

**My problem**

The expected behavior across the three analyses, for me, is that `k(i)` and `kSE(i)` would change but the p-values would remain the same - in other words, scaling the data should not make any model coefficient more or less statistically significant. This is contrary to the above scenarios, where the p-values change each time!

Please help me to debug this numerical issue - or explain whether this is in fact the expected behavior and I have misunderstood something. Thank you for reading this long post and helping - I tried to encapsulate all relevant problem details here.

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume you are controlling the random seed of the sampling so that's the same in all scenarios.

That taken care of, I think it may have something to do with the optimization problem you're trying to solve.
I have firsthand experience that tiny numerical changes (in my case, scaling the loglikelihood function by a factor, or equivalently: adding copies of all the datapoints) will change your result when the objective function is not convex.

I would try to derive the analytical gradient of the loglikelihood function in all of the parameters.
This should give you an idea of whether the optimization problem is convex.
If it is not convex, there are some things to do to make sure you get the real MLE.

- Optimize the function 1000 times and pick the estimate with the highest loglikelihood
- Change the tolerance and number of steps of the optimizer
- Try other optimizers, like trust-region searches or particle swarms

I would start by simulating a simpler version of this problem and build it up gradually to see where this behaviour starts happening. For example, start with just 1 parameter for the mean and 1 for the noise, and see what happens with the p values then.

Comment: Is this an answer, or an attempt to provide an answer? IMHO suggestions should first be added as comments, then, if an answer is clear, write an answer.

Comment: This is an attempt to provide an answer, but as you can see I have less than 50 reputation which means I'm unable to leave a comment.

Comment: We all started like that; did you try to join a second community; usually you get 100 points for the new community ;-)